# Mongoose throws Error: Field `type` is not in schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My Model has

```
type: {type: String, required: true, default: 'actual'},
```

Mongoose version: 3.8.40

But we get below error,

```
Field `type` is not in schema
```

Thanks

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#typeKey

Comment: Thanks @robertklep . Is there any option in 3.8.40 ?

Comment: Hmm good question, it doesn't look like [3.8](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/3.8.x/docs/guide.html) had something similar.

Comment: Thanks @robertklep. We need for 3.8, because of dependencies.

Comment: In that case it may be difficult to work around.